# How does mongodb $size work?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection "posts", and a post can have comments which is stored as an array on a post document, like so:

```
{
    ...
    comments : [ ... ]
    ...
}
```

If I want to count the number of comments on a particular post, I can do `{ $size : "$comments" }`. However, looking at the bson binary format, it does not look like it actually stores the size of the array anywhere, it is just a document with keys 0, 1, 2...

If that is the case, does it have to iterate through all the comments to count them? This seems inefficient, especially if you had a lot of posts with say over 1000 comments.

There is an obvious fix for this. Just store the count on the document.

```
{
    ...
    commentCount : 23,
    comments : [ ... ]
    ...
}
```

I am just curious if mongo does something behind the scenes where this is not a problem I should worry about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You honestly said this yourself:

> *"it is just a document with keys,  0, 1, 2..."*

Therefore the "last" key index is `n-1` of the size of the array. So if the last index is "49" then the size of the array is "50".

Also remember that the BSON itself is always parsed into a native representation. For the server this is a struct to represent the array and, yes it does contain the length property as well.

So it does not need to "iterate" and count, it just reads the information from what is already stored.

---

Actually, specifically it does exactly [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/expression.cpp#L2821-L2834):

```c++
Value ExpressionSize::evaluateInternal(Variables* vars) const {
    Value array = vpOperand[0]->evaluateInternal(vars);

    uassert(17124,
            str::stream() << "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: "
                          << typeName(array.getType()),
            array.getType() == Array);
    return Value::createIntOrLong(array.getArray().size());
}

REGISTER_EXPRESSION(size, ExpressionSize::parse);
const char* ExpressionSize::getOpName() const {
    return "$size";
}
```

Where you can see that after the internal evaluation it is simply reading the `size()` from the getter on the object.